# juju mongodb charm not found

Tags: 14.04, juju

On an Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) host, this command fails:

```
juju deploy mongodb
ERROR charm not found: cs:trusty/mongodb
```

I am attempting to follow this documentation:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/howto-node

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer can be inferred from a combination of reading:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-deploying

And this bug:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/mongodb/+bug/1312389

From the doc:

> Running this will do exactly what you expect - fetch the latest Juju charm for the series you are running [...]
>
> Juju usefully supports a system of namespaces that means you can actually deploy charms from a variety of sources. The default source is the charm store. The above command is the same as running:
>
> juju deploy cs:trusty/mongodb

Since you are running on a trusty host, juju defaults to looking for a trusty version of the charm. And from the bug, we can see that there is no trusty version of that charm yet.

The workaround is to deploy an older version of mongodb on Ubuntu 12.04 (precise):

```
juju deploy cs:precise/mongodb
```

until the mongodb charm is updated for trusty.

This workaround applies to any charm that has not yet been updated for 14.04.